# how do I link an external drive, external js file into a wordpress plugin that allows javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Here is the scenario.  I am running wordpress with the visual composer plugin that allows me to use "RAW js" and I wanted to attach my javascript from my computer to the site.  Problem is I am running into is, how do I type the path right if it has a directory?

I tried to use w3schools "try it yourself" to simulate how to attach it, but it fails to pick it up.

Here is what I typed:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-v.1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/Site/jquery/jquery-v.1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-v1.12.4.js"></script>
```

Obviously i can somply use google apis to pull the version.  But this is an example of attaching an external file into a web site coding area.  And this is a question specifically for the feature of the Visual Composer plugin for wordpress.  Also, if i have to type it into wordpress manually by  'wp_register_script' .  How do i write it to pull an external file?  The "C:" is replaced with a directory outside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can reference a local file like that (file:///) if your index.html is not open from local disk. Most browsers will simply not allow this operation (at all, or without special exceptions). Most probably you will see a corresponding error message on the console.

What you may try (at least I did it in some other system) is to insert javascript directly into the field that accepts raw html inside the script tag. meaning, that you copy/paste the script content from your file to there.

```
<script>
   console.log("Hello world!")
</script>
```